# How to get max viewable X-Value in Viewport

Tags: xna, c#

How can I calculate or get the farthest X-Value of a Viewport during gameplay?

Say a model is moving in from the right-hand side (beyond Viewport) and starting from a certain X-Value it is visible on the viewport. I'd like get that certain X-Value.

But the more I zoom out (Z-Axis) the greater the farthest visible X gets (*Max X*). How could I approach this?

[image]

Comment: For a perspective 3D viewport, you also need to consider `Z` of the model.  Or rather, max `X` is a function of `Z`.

Answer (score 1):

**What you probably want to use is the `BoundingFrustum` class** ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.boundingfrustum.aspx)).

A bounding frustum gives you a volume shaped like this:

[image: Bounding Frustum]

A bounding frustum created with your projection matrix will contain the volume you are interested in. You can then use the various `Intersects` or `Contains` overloads to test against various shapes (`BoundingBox` and `BoundingSphere`) that you can use to approximate the volume of your 3D model for culling purposes.